# hide Html elements by using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How can i hide html elements by using javascript 
if i have this html page

```
<body>

<h1>test</h1>

<div id="1" align="center" style="padding-top: 10%;" >
 <h1 style="color: #FFFFFF">fawazapp</h1>
 <p style="color: #C0C0C0;"> bbb</p>
 <p style="color: #FFFFFF;">aaaaaaaaa</p>

 </div>

<div id="2" align="center" style="padding-top: 10%;" >
 <h1 style="color: #FFFFFF">fawazapp</h1>
 <p style="color: #C0C0C0;"> bbb</p>
 <p style="color: #FFFFFF;">aaaaaaaaa</p>

 </div>

</body>
```

i want to hide all elements except  div with id number 2 to be page like this

```
<div id="2" align="center" style="padding-top: 10%;" >
 <h1 style="color: #FFFFFF">fawazapp</h1>
 <p style="color: #C0C0C0;"> bbb</p>
 <p style="color: #FFFFFF;">aaaaaaaaa</p>

 </div>
```

Comment: Your question is a little ambiguous. When do you want to do it? Is that the complete HTML of your page. Will you want the other DIVs to be shown back..?? etc .,etc. Could you please update your question with these answers ?

Comment: What does this have to do with Xcode and iOS?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In addition to DevlshOne's answer, you could also use css to make it not display:

```
var divOne = document.getElementById('1');
divOne.style.display='none';
```

There's a difference between the two.  With visibility hidden, the space will still be consumed by the div, but you can't see it.  With display='none', its as if its not there.

Pick the better one for you.

Answer (score 10):

you will need to use something like this:

```
document.getElementById("1").style.display = "none";
```

Answer (score 6):

Answers above are all basically correct, but you need to be aware of a difference between display = "none" & visibility = "hidden". With display "none" the element is removed from the layout of elements on the page. With visibility "hidden" the element still occupies its space, you just don't see it anymore.

Answer (score 2):

```
var divOne = document.getElementById('1');
divOne.style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

[`document.getElementById` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById)

Comment: Still this method occupy the space in the container. Just visibility is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQUERY : `$('#1').hide()`

Great