# Hide content in <div> using .html() without hiding inner <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have the following HTML code, generated by C#:

```
<div class="more-news-items" id="@id">
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <div style="text-align:center">
       <button class="newsfeed-hide">TOON MINDER</button>
       <button class="newsfeed-more">TOON MEER</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to hide the

```
<p>Content goes here</p>
```

using the following Javascript code, but I want to keep the buttons still in the div. How would I achieve this, and if it is not possible, how can I do this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    div.find('.newsfeed-hide').click(function () {

        $('.more-news-items').html('');
    });

});
```

Comment: Can you add a class or id to the p tag coming out of the c# as this will be a more future proof solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.newsfeed-hide').click(function () {
     $('div.more-news-items').children('p').hide();
  });
});
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.newsfeed-hide').click(function () {
      $('div.more-news-items p').hide();
   });
});
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.newsfeed-hide').click(function () {
      $(this).parent().siblings('p').hide();
   });
});
```

Comment: @KevinVoorn...if answer helped to solve your problem..then feel free to accept the answer..

Comment: I will, I need to wait 3 more minutes though :P

Comment: @KevinVoorn...no problem..happy to help you :)

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.newsfeed-hide').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().siblings('p').hide();
    });

});
```

This will hide a `p`'s that are siblings of the parent that the button is in.

But other posts are right in as much as if you want to hide all `p`'s in div's with the class `.more-news-items` you can select this using `$('.more-news-items p')` instead. Depending on the exact situation you are using this code in (i.e. if you will have more than one area and only want all `p`'s in all areas removed, or only the ones local to the button.

EDIT:

Remove the `$('.more-news-items').html('');` also, this will remove all html inside the `.more-news-items` div, which you do not want to do here.

Here is the live example: http://jsfiddle.net/lee_gladding/dujc66qd/

Comment: Also worth referencing this article with a CSS alternative, like mentioned, hide will still leave the padding/margins but displaying it as none by CSS will allow for the space to be erased entirely essentially 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17560867/hide-html-elements-by-using-javascript