# How do i hide a popup on newsletter response

Tags: javascript, popup

I have implemented  a popup when user tries to leave the website.
And i have attached this widget of a plugin.

This is how  the code looks for the main popup `id="bigie"`

And the message after successful subscription comes in

```
<span id="es_msg_pg">Subscribed successfully.</span>
```

[image]

The code which is responsible for adding `Subscribed successfully.` in the above code is

```
if (http_req.status == 200) 
        {
            if (http_req.readyState==4 || http_req.readyState=="complete")
            { 
                if((http_req.responseText).trim() == "subscribed-successfully")
                {
                    document.getElementById("es_msg_pg").innerHTML = "Subscribed successfully.";
                    document.getElementById("es_txt_email_pg").value="";
                    document.getElementById("bigie").hide ;
```

I added the  following code in the js file for the widget to hide the pop `document.getElementById("bigie").hide ;`
But it doesn't do anything

Please help what is i am doing wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [hide Html elements by using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17560867/hide-html-elements-by-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

`.hide` isn't a thing. You should use `.style.display = 'none'`:

```
document.getElementById("bigie").style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: The code for the popup is in the footer and and intially to keep the popup hidden i allrady have the style display = 'none' . . May be thats the issue??