# hiding options on a page that sorts things

Tags: javascript, css

I have a page that filters plastic balls
[based on quantity of the balls in the set and thier colors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FE2I.png)

Due to the nature of the system I am working on every color you see there is a different form with one checkbox option changed to a slider using CSS. Otherwise I cannot filter multicolored sets.

What I want to know is, **is it possible to hide some of those options and then show them with a click of the button?** Something like you can see with "Quantity" there. The only things I found about that is in a case with a single form.

Can I somehow make webpage to think "Color" is one form and proceed to hide the options from there?

I'm using CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: Hi cer1xo. It is possible. What have you tried? Can you merge the color checkboxes into one form? I think that would be easier for you.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17560867/hide-html-elements-by-using-javascript ( hide Html elements by using javascript ). Is it what you are after and a duplicate of your question?

Comment: As has been mentioned vanilla JavaScript has some tricks to help you. You might also experiment with some frameworks that allow you bind your input values like some of the examples on this page. https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#radio